# How to make this circuit

Tags: circuit-design

I want to create the following circuit: A piezoelectric receiver generates a certain voltage (AC) at a certain mechanical strain. If the voltage (at any point) reaches a certain value, an amplifier will increase the strength, and that should in turn control an electronic (like a phone) to do something (like send an sms). I don’t know what to do after installing the amplifier, do I need to convert analog to digital, and if so, how would I make it so that the electronic (take the phone for example) will execute code once the signal reaches it?

Comment: It basically comes down to how a phone works. The rest is a simple comparator and maybe a monostable but, without knowing how the phone interface works, who can be sure.

Answer (score 2):

the output of the piezo can be send an amplifier that amplifies the AC(do make sure if using a transistor for this that you will need to bias the voltage with DC). Then the amplified output sent to a ADC so that it could be processed by the microcontroller (an arduino would do in this case). Then code that and connect it to the other electronic (do check which medium suits better UART, USB or Bluetooth).